# Use jQuery to set selected index of a dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, reset

I have seen other posts here at `SO` about this very same subject, but I have not found a solution that is setting the select using `jQuery`.

I have a dropdown that looks like this:

```
<select type="select" id="docsList" name="docsList"> 
    <option id="defaultListItem" value="0">Select a Document...</option> 
    <option value="38">Document 1</option> 
    <option value="35">Document 2</option> 
    <option value="46">Document 3</option> 
    <option value="45">Document 4</option>          
</select>
```

I need to reset the dropdown within an `$.ajax()` *success* function. I've used the following:

```
$('select#docsList option:selected').val('0');
$('select#docsList').attr('selectedIndex', 0);
```

... and some others.

I'm beginning to think this code is fine and I've got something else going on preventing resetting the dropdown.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. You don't need jQuery to get/set a `<select>`'s `selectedIndex`.

```
$('#docsList').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
```

When setting the value of a `<select>`, call `.val()` on the `<select>`, not on one of its `<option>`s.

```
$('#docsList').val('0');
```

Comment: All of the others work, too, but kudos to Matt for his explanation and the simplest solution! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Good post, should also be noted that `selectedIndex` is a property.

Comment: @GoldBishop thanks. Why should that be noted? I don't see what that adds. Maybe you should elaborate.

Comment: Cause JQuery/JS will allow you to do whatever you want.  And although it looks well and fine, when you goto try and use the assignement, it may not be evident until you try and debug it.  Personal experience of course.

Answer (score 7):

`$('#docsList option[value=0]').attr('selected', 'selected');`
This will set the `<option>` with the value attribute set to 0 as the selected option.

Answer (score 4):

Matt's answer has a small flaw:

```
$('#docsList').val('0');
```

The code above will not work in IE 9 when not in Compatibility Mode.  The following worked cross browsers for me:

```
document.getElementById('docsList').selectedIndex = 0;
```

Thanks for the pointer in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 3):

You want `$('select#docsList').val('0');`  See example at: http://jsfiddle.net/uE2YN/

Comment: @GuyCohen Are you sure that the id in the selector matches the id of your select element? Are you sure that the code is running after the DOM is completely loaded?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I could not reply sooner.
I tested your sample in jsfiddle.... now I know why - when I set the value to 1 (just to see if you can select other than the first item) I did not add the value 1 to the second item.

In any case my working sample is this:

$('#mylistname').prop('selectedIndex', 1);

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".btn-reset").click(function () {
    $('#docsList').val('123er43f-12fr-7hgy-ju78-kju345uy65r3');
    $('#docsList').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```