# Jquery/Ajax to update a TABLE[ASP.NET Core MVC]

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm not sure how to refresh table data after I use AJAX Jquery.

I need help. I've a razor view, on button click button I am sending a post request with textbox and dropdown selected values, then in controller, passed Json response status for toaster.

The next controller returns a view and displays toaster status correctly.

The main problem is that I don't know how to refresh that table with newly inserted records after toaster response status.

This is my view of the Controller:

```
@using SimplCommerce.WebHost.Models @model dynamic
<body>
    <form method="post" id="map_Form">

        <table id="tbl_btn">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <button type="submit">Catalog Mapping</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="tb_properties" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                @foreach (ApiMapDbViewModel itemApiProp in Model.dynApiPropModel)
                {
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="@itemApiProp.Key" readonly="readonly" />
                        <hr />

                        <select>
                            <option value="">-Select-</option>
                            @foreach (ApiMapDbViewModel itemK360Prop in Model.dynK360PropModel)
                            {
                                <option>@itemK360Prop.Key</option>

                            }
                        </select>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="partial_div">
            @Html.Partial("KPartialIndex")
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>

@section scripts{

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("button[type='submit']").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var properties = [];
                $("#tb_properties tr:first").find("td").each(function (index, item) {
                    var propertyname = $(item).find("input[type='text']").val();
                    var selctedvalue = $(item).find("select").val();
                    properties.push('"' + propertyname + '":"' + selctedvalue + '"');
                });
                var jsonstr = '{' + properties.join(",") + '}';
                var jsobject = JSON.parse(jsonstr);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "/KMap/Insert",
                    data: { jsonModel: jsobject },
                    success: function (response) {
                        toastr.error(response.status + "----->" + response.message);
                        //info//warning//error//success
                        toastr.options = {
                            "closeButton": false,
                            "debug": false,
                            "newestOnTop": false,
                            "progressBar": false,
                            "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
                            "preventDuplicates": false,
                            "onclick": null,
                            "showDuration": "1000",
                            "hideDuration": "1000",
                            "timeOut": "5000",
                            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                            "showEasing": "swing",
                            "hideEasing": "linear",
                            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                        };

                        $("#map_Form select").val("");
                        $("#partial_div").load("/KMap/LoadPartialViewOnPost"); // not working

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('in error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

This is my partial view:

```
 @using SimplCommerce.WebHost.Models @model dynamic
<table>   
    @if (Model.dynMappedDataModel != null)

    {
        @foreach (K360mapMaster itemMappedData in Model.dynMappedDataModel)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@itemMappedData.ClientCatalog</td>
                <td>@itemMappedData.K360catalog</td>
            </tr>
        }

    }
</table>
```

This is my controller:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        dynamic dynModel = new ExpandoObject();
        dynModel.dynApiPropModel = GetListApiProp();
        dynModel.dynMappedDataModel = ListMappedData();
        dynModel.dynK360PropModel = GetListK360Prop();
        return View(dynModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult LoadPartialViewOnPost()
    {
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.dynMappedDataModel = ListMappedData();
        return PartialView("KPartialIndex", mymodel);
    }

    public List<K360mapMaster> ListMappedData()
    {
        List<K360mapMaster> items = new List<K360mapMaster>();
        var query = from K360mapMaster in _context.K360mapMasters
                    select K360mapMaster;
        var mappings = query.ToList();
        foreach (var mappingData in mappings)
        {
            items.Add(new K360mapMaster()
            {
               
                ClientCatalog = mappingData.ClientCatalog,
                K360catalog = mappingData.K360catalog

            });
        }
        return items;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Insert(ApiJsonViewModel jsonModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors, (y, z) => z.Exception.Message);
            return BadRequest(errors);
        }
        Type type = jsonModel.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
        List<K360mapMaster> K360mapListObj = new List<K360mapMaster>();

        K360mapListObj = props.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString()))
                                        .Select(c => new K360mapMaster() { ClientCatalog = c.Name, K360catalog = c.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString() })
                                        .ToList();
        if (K360mapListObj.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var ListCatalogs = K360mapListObj.Select(l => l.ClientCatalog).ToList();

                foreach (var item in ListCatalogs)
                {
                    var DbCatalogs = (from p in _context.K360mapMasters
                                      where p.ClientCatalog == item
                                      select p).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (DbCatalogs != null)
                    {

                        return Json(new { Status = "This is an information notification provided by K360 eCommerce. ", Message = "Selected catalog  " + item + "  already mapped." });
                    }
                }
                _context.K360mapMasters.AddRange(K360mapListObj);
                _context.SaveChanges();                   
               return Json(new { Status = "This is a success notification from K360 eCommerce. ", Message = "Product catalog's mapped sucessfully." });
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { Status = "This is an error notification provided by K360 eCommerce. ", Message = "Mapping failed" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "This is a warning notification provided by K360 eCommerce. ", Message = "No product catalog selected." });
        }

    }
```

I want to refresh the new insert records after toaster response status. Please help thanks

The issue is fixed now.

Provided id for the table in partial view.

and in Jquery Sucess function added below piece of code

```
  $("#par_tbl").load(window.location.href + " #par_tbl");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JQuery to loop through the `<td>` elements, and use JQuery Selector gets the property name and selected value. Then, according to the value to generate a JS object, and use JQuery Ajax to call the controller action method and store the object into the database.

Please refer the following sample code:

Models:

```
public class SMJsonModel
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
}
public class PropertyInfoK360
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SupermarketController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //initial data:
        List<SMJsonModel> JsonResultList = new List<SMJsonModel>()
        {
            new SMJsonModel(){
                title="Brown eggs",
                type="dairy",
                description="Raw organic brown eggs in a basket",
                fileName="0.jpg",
                height = "600",
                width="400",
                price="28.1",
                rating="4"
            }
        };
        ViewData["K360DbPropVD"] = new List<PropertyInfoK360>()
        {
            new PropertyInfoK360(){ Value="AAA", Key="AAA"},
             new PropertyInfoK360(){ Value="BBB", Key="BBB"},
              new PropertyInfoK360(){ Value="CCC", Key="CCC"},
               new PropertyInfoK360(){ Value="DDD", Key="DDD"},
                new PropertyInfoK360(){ Value="EEE", Key="EEE"},
                 new PropertyInfoK360(){ Value="FFF", Key="FFF"},
                  new PropertyInfoK360(){ Value="GGG", Key="GGG"},
        };
        return View(JsonResultList);
    }
    // this method is used to insert data into database.
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(SMJsonModel jsonModel)
    {
        //insert object into database.

        return Ok("success");
    }
}
```

Index View page:

```
@model IEnumerable<netcore5.Models.SMJsonModel> 
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tb_properties" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties())
                {
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="@property.Name" class="form-control" />
                        @{var K360list = new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["K360DbPropVD"], "Value", "Key");}
                        <select asp-items="K360list" class="form-control"></select>

                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Catalog Mapping</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts{
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("button[type='submit']").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var properties = []; //define an array to store the property name and the selected value.
            $("#tb_properties tr:first").find("td").each(function (index, item) {
                var propertyname = $(item).find("input[type='text']").val();
                var selctedvalue = $(item).find("select").val(); 
                properties.push('"' + propertyname + '":"' + selctedvalue + '"');
            }); 
            //According the properties to genereate the json string.
            var jsonstr = '{' + properties.join(",") + '}';
            //convert the json string to js object.
            var jsobject = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
            //call the Inset method and store data into the database.
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Supermarket/Insert",
                data: { jsonModel: jsobject },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response); 

                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('in error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

**Update**

As mentioned in the comment, to store the JsModel's property name as the first column and its value as the second column's value in the K360ECommerceS table, you could refer the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(SMJsonModel jsonModel)
    {
        //insert object into database.
        //required using System.Reflection; 
        //use GetType() and GetProperties() method to get object's property name and its value.
        Type type = jsonModel.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

        List<K360Master> k360Masters = new List<K360Master>(); 
        foreach(var item in props)
        {
            K360Master master = new K360Master()
            {
                ClientCatalog = item.Name,
                K360catalog = item.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString()
            };
            k360Masters.Add(master);
        }
        _context.K360Master.AddRange(k360Masters);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        return Ok("success");
    }
```

After that, the result in the K360Master table as below:

[image]

[Note] In the above sample, my DBContext as below, it will insert data into the K360Master table, please check your code and make sure you are using the correct Entity and Tables.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<K360Master> K360Master { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

> Only if we select all the 8 dropdownlist then only it gets inserted.
> Not able to select only 2 or 3 dropdownlist and it shows Cannot insert
> the value NULL into column 'K360Catalog'. Its not null column. please
> guide me. task needs to finished by today eod

In the Insert method, you could check whether the value is null or not before save them to database. Code as below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(SMJsonModel jsonModel)
    {
        //insert object into database.

        Type type = jsonModel.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

        List<K360Master> k360Masters = new List<K360Master>(); 
        foreach(var item in props)
        {
            //check if the value is null or not.
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString()))
            {
                K360Master master = new K360Master()
                {
                    ClientCatalog = item.Name,
                    K360catalog = item.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString()
                };
                // if the value is not null, add it to the list
                k360Masters.Add(master);
            }
        }
        //insert the list items into database.
        _context.K360Master.AddRange(k360Masters);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        return Ok("success");
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

**Update**

From your description, if you don't want to use for each statement to loop through the 8 fields, you could try to use LINQ where clause to filter the data. And, if you want to return multiple value from controller action method to the Ajax function, you could refer a Json result. please check the following sample:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(SMJsonModel jsonModel)
    {
        //insert object into database.

        Type type = jsonModel.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

        List<K360Master> k360Masters = new List<K360Master>(); 
        //using where clause to filter data.
        k360Masters = props.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString()))
                                        .Select(c=> new K360Master() { ClientCatalog= c.Name,  K360catalog = c.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString() })
                                        .ToList(); 
        if(k360Masters.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                //foreach (var item in props)
                //{
                //    //check if the value is null or not. if the value is not null, add it to the list
                //    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString()))
                //    {
                //        K360Master master = new K360Master()
                //        {
                //            ClientCatalog = item.Name,
                //            K360catalog = item.GetValue(jsonModel, null)?.ToString()
                //        };
                //        k360Masters.Add(master);
                //    }
                //}

                _context.K360Master.AddRange(k360Masters);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { Status = "Success", Message = "Insert Success!" }); 
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = "Fail to insert data into database" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "Warning", Message = "No selected item" });
        }
    }
```

Ajax code:

```
        //According the properties to genereate the json string.
        var jsonstr = '{' + properties.join(",") + '}';
        //convert the json string to js object.
        var jsobject = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Supermarket/Insert",
            data: { jsonModel: jsobject },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.status + "--" + response.message);
                //then, based on the status to choose 
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('in error');
            }
        });
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your support. Will look ino into it and get back to you soon

Comment: Everything working fine except. I need to insert into sep table having 2 fields

Comment: <input type="text" asp-for="ClientCatalog" value="@jitems.ClientCatalog" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                            <select asp-for="K360catalog" asp-items="@ViewBag.FruitsVbag"></select>

Comment: <input type="text"  value="@property.Name" class="form-control" />
                        @{var K360list = new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["K360DbPropVD"], "Value", "Key");}
                        <select asp-items="K360list" class="form-control"></select>

Comment: How to include here asp-for or we able to access in controller. public IActionResult Insert(JsModel jsonModel)
        {

Comment: public IActionResult Index(K360Master K360MapModel)
        {
   _context.K360Masters.Add(K360MapModel);
         _context.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: please help me to insert records into db

Comment: Hi @NSiva, Do you mean at present you are using asp-for to bind and display data, and you want to get these values and call the controller action method to insert data? If that is the case, it is similar with above code. In the above sample, we are using JQuery selector to find the elements based on the html elements. Now, if we are using asp-for, the element's id and name attribute should be the property name, try to use F12 developer tools to check it. Then, we can use JQuery to get the value based on the id or name, then, use JQuery Ajax call the Insert method (with parameters) to insert.

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv, no i changed code based on your sample only. I need to insert values into a new table in 2 fields. Now if i choose 8 dropdwonlist, in controller insert method model all are populating in array.I need to insert all 8 records in single click. For example in 8 records, first record having title(prop name) in left side and selected value in right side. i need to insert prop name in one field and selected value in another field of table. Need to insert all selected 8 records in a single click. please help me.i am struck up for more than 6 hours. I will post updated code now

Comment: Hi @NSiva, According to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfRPy.png), do you mean you want to store the JsModel's property name as the first column and its value as the second column's value in the K360ECommerceS table (In the Insert method, you are using `_context.K360Masters`, please make sure it will store value in the K360ECommerceS table)? The result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxXba.png)?

Comment: Yes you are correct.As per your screenshot i need to store values in table k360master. But its not working.    // this method is used to insert data into database.
 public IActionResult Insert(JsModel jsonModel) { K360Master KMModel = new K360Master();  _context.K360Masters.Add(KMModel);_context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Hi @NSiva, Please check my Update, I'm using the GetType() and GetProperties() method to get the object's property name and its value, then, insert into database. It works well on my machine, you can have a try.

Comment: thanks a lot for your timing effort.Will look into it and get back back to you.

Comment: thanks a lot from my bottom of my heart for all your kind efforts.It working like a gem. I am not thinking to create a list...Anyhow its very good learning task for me.

Comment: Need to show alert after successfully inserted as dialog popup. Need to do validation like if there is already inserted record in first field ClientCatalog then need to show red alert and not able to insert again. I am zero in jquery. Now i need to learn fastly as major part is working fine with jquery. If you have any sample or sample links for popup alert jquery and validation please share with me. I searched a lot but hard to found yet.

Comment: You could try to use the [Bootstrap Alerts](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp) and [Bootstrap 4 Toast](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_toast.asp) to alert the notification message, sample code [like this](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/oNYwbmw), the result looks like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3mqe.gif). In the Ajax success or error function, you could call the toast() method to show or hidden the alert message. More detail information about using Toast, see [Toasts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/).

Comment: again thanks a lot for your kind suggestions. Will look into it and get back to you if i face serious issues again

Comment: now again serious problem arises... Only if we select all the 8 dropdownlist then only it gets inserted. Not able to select only 2 or 3 dropdownlist and it shows Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'K360Catalog'. Its not null column. please guide me. task needs to finished by today eod

Comment: <option value="">-Select-</option>..its must for all dropdownlist... they will choose one or dropdownlist .. sometimes all... I think you submit button on jquery by reading table properties. dont know how to handle this

Comment: Hi @NSiva, Check my update, add an if statement in the Insert method and check whether the value is null or not, then, if the value is not null, insert them into the database.

Comment: Hi @Zhi Lv once again appreciate your valuable effort. Its working fine now

Comment: i am not able to understand these sucess/failure message.success: function (response) {console.log(response);},error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log('in error');return Ok("success");  Will you update me a simple javascipt alert box if records inserted sucessfully or failure alert box if they didnt select any other.. I tried  ViewBag.Message = "your Catalogs has been Mapped."; <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function () {alert("@ViewBag.Message"); };</script> but its not working

Comment: if no dropdown selected then it loop through foreach loop 8 times then return, if 2 dropdown selected then it loop through next 6 times.  foreach (var item in props). Is any way to define method like if no dropdown selected then exit loop with alert message and 2 inserted then inserted message for that 2 records with field names. if all inserted then all records inserted like that. sorry to disturb you a lot.

Comment: Hi @NSiva, Please check the latest Update, try to use *Where* clause to filter data, and return Json result from the controller action method. By the way, since this thread is too long, if you have any further question, I suggest you could try to create a new thread, then, the more community members will focus on your question. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support. ya sure will create a new thread if i get any issue

Comment: Everything Working fine. Thanks. How to reset dropdownlist selection back to default select(-Select-) .. value null ...after every submit click..

Comment: Hi @NSiva, In the Ajax success function, use JQuery to find all `select` elements and change the selectedIndex attribute. code as below: `success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.status + "--" + response.message);
                    //then, based on the status to choose 
                    //find the select elements and change the selectedIndex.
                    $("select").each(function (index, item) {
                        $(item).get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
                    });}`. Reference [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433258/).

Comment: Thanks once again for your timing support. Last and final correction . Sure will create a new thread hereafter.

Comment: If Client Catalog ie json values already inserted into database, we need to show alert  showing this property is already saved. Only this task missing. Thanks once again for all your efforts

Comment: To check for already existing records, i have updated working code.But i am not sure whether its right approach.please check once

Comment: I have created one data table to show inserted records in the same view page. After insert, we are returning alert messages as json so not able to redirect view. Hence the updated records not showing in the datatable. i have tried form post, html begin form but nothing worth. please suggest me .. we are using jquery to post.

Comment: I have put location.reload(true); in jquery sucess function. Now page gets refreshed. But it looks more freeky refresh not like classic asp.net page refresh.

Comment: I have created a new thread. In free time please have look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66287159/im-not-understanding-something-fundamental-in-my-new-project-in-asp-net-mvc-cor

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv, location.reload(true) makes freaky!!!. Even manual refresh is better than this. Any other alternative way?

Comment: asked few clarifications on update section.please help

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed now.

Provided id for the table in partial view.

and in Jquery Sucess function added below piece of code

$("#par_tbl").load(window.location.href + " #par_tbl");